# Trouble installing Python package group (STSCI)

Tags: python, gcc, installation

I'm trying to install a set of packages called STSCI (Space Telescope Science Institute). However, I get the following error, and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Here's the full terminal log:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stscipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stscipython-2.14-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): d2to1>=0.2.9,<=0.2.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/d2to1-0.2.10-py2.7.egg (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.distutils>=0.3.2,<=0.3.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyfits>=3.1.1,<=3.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.tools>=3.2,<=3.2.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.ndimage>=0.10.0,<=0.10.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.convolve>=2.1,<=2.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pywcs>=1.10.2,<=1.10.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stwcs>=1.1.0,<=1.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.stimage>=0.2,<=0.2.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.imagestats>=1.4,<=1.4.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.imagemanip>=1.1,<=1.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.image>=2.1,<=2.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pysynphot>=0.9.5,<=0.9.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pydrizzle>=6.4.0,<=6.4.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nictools>=1.1.0,<=1.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): calcos>=2.19.7,<=2.19.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): astrolib.coords>=0.39.4,<=0.39.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wfpc2tools>=1.0.1,<=1.0.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wfc3tools>=1.1,<=1.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.sphinxext>=1.2.1,<=1.2.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stsci.numdisplay>=1.6,<=1.6.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stistools>=1.0.1,<=1.0.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): reftools>=1.6.4,<=1.6.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stscipython)
Downloading/unpacking pyraf>=2.1,<=2.1.99 (from stscipython)
  Downloading pyraf-2.1.1.tar.gz (2.0MB): 2.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyraf

    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyraf_install_src.ps' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyraf_install_src.pdf' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'src'
Downloading/unpacking opuscoords>=1.0.1,<=1.0.99 (from stscipython)
  Downloading opuscoords-1.0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package opuscoords

Downloading/unpacking multidrizzle>=3.4.0,<=3.4.99 (from stscipython)
  Downloading multidrizzle-3.4.0.tar.gz (64kB): 64kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package multidrizzle

Downloading/unpacking fitsblender>=0.2,<=0.2.99 (from stscipython)
  Downloading fitsblender-0.2.tar.gz (64kB): 64kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package fitsblender

Downloading/unpacking drizzlepac>=1.1.8,<=1.1.99 (from stscipython)
  Downloading drizzlepac-1.1.8.tar.gz (657kB): 657kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package drizzlepac

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): costools>=1.1,<=1.1.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/costools-1.1-py2.7.egg (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): acstools>=1.7.2,<=1.7.99 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/acstools-1.7.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg (from stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from d2to1>=0.2.9,<=0.2.99->stscipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyfits>=3.1.1,<=3.1.99->stscipython)
Installing collected packages: pyraf, opuscoords, multidrizzle, fitsblender, drizzlepac
  Running setup.py install for pyraf
    building 'pyraf.sscanfmodule' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o
    src/sscanfmodule.c: In function ‘initsscanf’:
    src/sscanfmodule.c:443:14: warning: variable ‘m’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf/sscanfmodule.so
    building 'pyraf.xutilmodule' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/xutil.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/xutil.o
    src/xutil.c:2:19: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vidur/pyraf/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1XxMCU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/graphcap.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/subproc.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/splash.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gkicmd.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafcompleter.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/textattrib.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/urwutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/pyrafTk.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/fontdata.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/MplCanvasAdapter.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/generic.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafhelp.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/iraffunctions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafdisplay.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafnames.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gki_psikern_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gkitkbase.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/pyrafglobals.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafexecute.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/ipython_api.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gki_sys_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafgwcs.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/epar.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/urwfiledlg.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gkigcur.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/GkiMpl.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/clscan.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafpar.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/cl2py.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gwm.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/clcache.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/dirdbm.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafecl.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/msgiowidget.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gkitkplot.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/dirshelve.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/iraf.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gki.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafimport.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/iraftask.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/newWindowHack.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/filecache.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/cgeneric.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/Ptkplot.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/pycmdline.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/gkiiraf.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/msgiobuffer.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/tpar.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/aqutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/wutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafukey.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/cltoken.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/tkplottext.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafimcur.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/cllinecache.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/irafinst.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/pseteparoption.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/clparse.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/describe.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/clast.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

copying lib/pyraf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf

running build_ext

running pre_hook pyraf_setup.build_ext_hook for command build_ext

building 'pyraf.sscanfmodule' extension

creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/sscanfmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o

src/sscanfmodule.c: In function ‘initsscanf’:

src/sscanfmodule.c:443:14: warning: variable ‘m’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/sscanfmodule.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/pyraf/sscanfmodule.so

building 'pyraf.xutilmodule' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/xutil.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/xutil.o

src/xutil.c:2:19: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So what's the easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `libx11-dev`.

Use

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you as usual, Sukrit.